# What is the meaning of Dr. Cawley words?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1130884/synopsis)

> Dr. Cawley tells Teddy that his real name is Laeddis, and he shows him
>   on a chalkboard that his full name and Laeddis's are an anagram; that
>   is, all the letters in his name can be rearranged to spell Laeddis's
>   full name. The same thing with his wife's name and Rachel's.

So What is the meaning of Dr. Cawley words?

Comment: The sentences you quote are quite straightforward (though the thought may not be very straightforward and involving puzzles; the meaning of *anagram* is also explained in the quote), so I'm not sure which part you don't understand. Also note that it isn't clear in the quote what exactly Dr. Cawley said. The quote is more like a description of what happened in the scene. (Even "his real name is Laeddis" in its direct speech (i.e., "Your real name is Laeddis.") probably isn't in exact words.)

Answer (score 1):

On first reading, my impression was that Dr. Cawley's full name and Teddy's full name are anagrams. It also wasn't clear whose wife "his wife" meant. I took this to mean Dr. Cawley's wife and Rachel. So from first reading, it wasn't clear whose names are being compared.

It turns out that Edward "Teddy" Daniels is a persona that Teddy made up. His real name is Andrew Laeddis. So, now it is clear that the two names are anagrams of one another.

> **Edward Daniels**
>   **Andrew Laeddis**

In other words, Teddy's fake full name is an anagram of his real full name.

This same is true of his wife's name.

> **Rachel Solando** (fake)
>   **Dolores Chanal** (real)